# Visual studio copy folders to remote machine not working

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to copy a whole folder with all the files it has from local machine to remote machine selected path?
In visual studio under project properties, I have Copy Sources and Build Events->Pre-Build Event, which help me to copy files from my local machine to the remote, but those options do not allow me to copy a folders over, only a files.

Since I have a big amount of files it seems weird to specify every file that I wish to copy to remote instead of specifying the folder.

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I have had the exact same need (or desire for ease of work) for quite a long time, but I didn't came into re-attempting it on a new VS Make Linux project setup until recently. You may track the issue I just reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1252757/vslinux-additional-sources-to-copy-ignores-folders.html), where we may only have any luck. Apparently the folder copy simply isn't supported.